# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka dynamic channel - specify common producer properties

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

Using BinderAwareChannelResolver of spring-cloud-stream kafka , I am dynamically resolving the channels based on an event, Since I have many producer channels and all the channels output kafka messages are going to be consumed by non-spring applications i need to set the headerMode of each channel as raw in application.properties which makes my configuration messy, Is there a way to specify the headerMode = raw common for all the producers that i use rather than specifying for each channel individually.